# ¿Saber si mi aplicación se ejecuta en 32 o 64 bits en java?

Tags: java

Quiero saber si en java se puede detectar la arquitectura donde está corriendo la aplicación, 32 o 64 bits. Si se puede, pues denme algún ejemplito de código, por favor.

He buscado en internet y solo sale como resolver problemas de dll que se ejecutan en la otra arquitectura.

Comment: Gracias, no me imagine que fuera tan facil
Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás buscando el valor de la siguiente propiedad de sistema: `"os.arch"` que según la documentación devuelve "Operating system architecture" o "Arquitectura del sistema operativo".

Lo puedes obtener utilizando el siguiente código:

```
System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

En mi caso, me devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
amd64
```

Más información sobre obtener propiedades del sistema en Java: [Tutoriales de Java: Propiedades del sistema](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) (en inglés)

Comment: ¿Alguna razón para obtener el voto en negativo? Ah, lo olvidaba, el odio sin sentido ;)

Comment: **`sun.arch.data.model`** es otra propiedad del sistema que contiene un valor más *directo*:`32` o `64`. Por cierto, +1.

Comment: @PaulVargas ¿esa propiedad no será de las que ponen en HotSpot y que si se utiliza una VM distinta como la de IBM puede que no esté registrada?

Comment: Lo dices por el `sun.`, ¿verdad?, pero sí existe en la de IBM.

Comment: @PaulVargas sí, lo digo por el `sun.arch.data.model` puesto que `sun` es un nombre que parece ser propio del viejo Sun (ahora Oracle) y que puede ser reemplazado en otras VMs.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es mi forma de validar a través de la propiedad `System.getProperty("os.arch")` con la cual se obtiene la arquitectura del SO:

```
if(System.getProperty("os.arch").equals("x86")){
    //32 bits;
}else{
   // 64 bits;
}
```

Para complementar esta respuesta, existe otra forma definida la cual es descrita **[aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748673/how-can-i-check-the-bitness-of-my-os-using-java-j2se-not-os-arch/5940770#5940770)**

```
String arch = System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE");
String wow64Arch = System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432");

String realArch = arch.endsWith("64")
                  || wow64Arch != null && wow64Arch.endsWith("64")
                      ? "64" : "32";
```

Comment: gracias el ultimo codigo es lo que estaba buscando! :)